# SQL Server ERRORLOG way too big

Tags: sql-server, error-log

I'm running SQL Server 2014 on a VPS with 150Gb SSD. Today, I found that my hard disk was full 100% and there's a very large file from SQL Server Error log that was 45.7Gb.

I tried manually delete the file, but Windows says the disk space doesn't change at all.

How can I delete this file? I don't need the error log data, it's fine for me to delete it and regain the disk space.

[image]

I checked the file; it is so large due to failed login attempts. But here I want to delete the file first, these following commands didn't delete it, could u please give me some ideas?

Answer (score 2):

You have to rotate error log to release the file lock kept by SQL Server process. Please execute this procedure:

```
EXEC sp_cycle_errorlog ;
```

Did you check content of the error log? There should be a reason why it's so big and you can find the answer only by checking the content of that file.

You can use PowerShell to display last X lines in the file:

```sh
Get-Content -Tail 1000 PATH_TO_LOG_FILE
```

Your error log file has a suffix `.4`. That means that it's not the active file for writing the error messages by the server process. You can manually delete it.

Answer (score 2):

You can limit the number and size of SQL Server error log files to avoid excessive space. This can be done from SSMS Object Explorer by right-clicking on the SQL Server Logs folder and selecting Configure. Alternatively, use a T-SQL script like the below example that limits the number of error logs to 10 files of up to 100MB each for your default instance:

```
EXEC master..xp_instance_regwrite N'HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE', N'Software\Microsoft\MSSQLServer\MSSQLServer'
    , N'ErrorLogSizeInKb'
    , REG_DWORD
    , 100;
EXEC master..xp_instance_regwrite N'HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE'
    , N'Software\Microsoft\MSSQLServer\MSSQLServer'
    , N'NumErrorLogs'
    , REG_DWORD
    , 10;
```

Examine the log to identify and remediate the root cause for the excessive size. The reason could be repeated login failures due to an attack, misconfigured application, repeated stack dumps, etc.

To view the current log, double-click on it from SSMS Object Explorer under Management-->SQL Server Logs or with the query below. In either case, you may need to stop the query due to the very large log size but the sampled records should be enough to identify the cause.

```
EXEC xp_readerrorlog 0, 1;
```

---

> But here I want to delete the file first, these following commands didn't delete it, could u please give me some ideas?

The old files will be deleted automatically once you've cycled through the max number of files (10 in my example). You can also manually delete the large `errorlog.n` files, like `errorlog.4` in your screen shot.